# Issue with running hadoop job locally

Tags: hadoop

I have run a hadoop job like following:

hadoop jar VoteCount.jar /user/joy/District1 /user/joy/Result_District1

```
16/03/26 16:18:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
16/03/26 16:18:30 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local911715097_0001
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local911715097_0001_m_000000_0
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/joy/District1/booth-1.txt:0+70
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 110; bufvoid = 104857600
16/03/26 16:18:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214360(104857440); length = 37/6553600
```

But I cannot browse the job, while typing http://localhost:8080/ in my browser, it keeps coming connection refused and while checking whether the output folder has been created by following command:

```
    hadoop fs -ls /user/joy/Result_District1
```

it is showing one temporary folder has been generated, no part-XXXXX file has been generated.

My hadoop configurations are as follows:

etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
 configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:50070/ for accessing HDFS.

It seems like your job has not run properly. Can you paste the entire log?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your job was successful or not you can do this by visiting 
http://localhost:50070/ now go to destination folder which you mentioned when you ran job on hadoop. In that folder you must be having a file name "_SUCCESS" if you are not having this file in that folder it means your job was unsuccessful.

localhost:8080 belongs to name node so if you are using version older then Hadoop 2.x then you might face such problem.
So it will be better you check your job status from 50070.

hope this answer your question. If not please share your detailed log so that I can be more specific.